# StableBaselines3 - NotImplementedError: observation space is not supported

Tags: reinforcement-learning, stable-baselines

I am trying to run `cleanrl` on the `Pendulum-v1` environment. I did that by going [here](https://github.com/vwxyzjn/cleanrl/blob/master/cleanrl/sac_continuous_action.py) and changing the default `env-id` to `parser.add_argument("--env-id", type=str, default="Pendulum-v1",help="the id of the environment")`

However, I keep getting the error - `NotImplementedError: Box([-1. -1. -8.], [1. 1. 8.], (3,), <class 'numpy.float32'>) observation space is not supported`

Therefore, I debugged this error to the ReplayBuffer that was imported from `SB3`. This is the [problem function](https://github.com/DLR-RM/stable-baselines3/blob/master/stable_baselines3/common/preprocessing.py) -

```
def get_obs_shape(
    observation_space: spaces.Space,
) -> Union[Tuple[int, ...], Dict[str, Tuple[int, ...]]]:
    """
    Get the shape of the observation (useful for the buffers).

    :param observation_space:
    :return:
    """
    if isinstance(observation_space, spaces.Box):
        return observation_space.shape
    elif isinstance(observation_space, spaces.Discrete):
        # Observation is an int
        return (1,)
    elif isinstance(observation_space, spaces.MultiDiscrete):
        # Number of discrete features
        return (int(len(observation_space.nvec)),)
    elif isinstance(observation_space, spaces.MultiBinary):
        # Number of binary features
        return observation_space.shape
    elif isinstance(observation_space, spaces.Dict):
        return {key: get_obs_shape(subspace) for (key, subspace) in observation_space.spaces.items()}  # type: ignore[misc]

    else:
        raise NotImplementedError(f"{observation_space} observation space is not supported")
```

I tried to print `observation_space` shape and this is what I got -

`Box([-1. -1. -8.], [1. 1. 8.], (3,), float32)`. Any idea why SB3 is not accepting my observation shape?